# Datasets - Menu to switch between tables in form

Tags: c#, list, dataset

I'm having a bit of difficulty with datasets in C#. I know how to load datasets and everything, and I can drag a table from the dataset into the form window and it displays the columns etc of that table. However, I would like to display every single table in the form, but in a clean way. Is there a way to create a dropdownlist for example, that will display all the tables in the data set, and then I can select the one I want and then display the columns, etc? Just need a way to display tables in the form and navigate between them and have them display their data. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create an instance of DataSet (typed dataset) (say DatabaseDataSet)

```
DatabaseDataSet ds = new DatabaseDataSet();
```

Then create adapter's instance which is an autogenerated class.

```
DatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.yourTableTableAdapter adp;
adp=new DatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.yourTableTableAdapter();
```

Pupulate the datatable object and push into to ds.

```
adp.Fill(ds.yourTable);
```

Use DataBinding technique to show data from the dataset object.

```
comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables["yourTable"];
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "column1";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "column2";
```

Off-topic:Use Collections, LINQ and Entity framework. The DataSet is bit outdated and it has many problems. Please take a look at this MSDN  post.

[DataSets vs. Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163751.aspx)